# how to click on a link obtain by xpath extractor in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I need to click on the first link of a response, I extracted the path of the link, can anyone suggest how to click on it.

Answer (score 1):

It's much better to use [CSS/ JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor) for this as page is HTML.

It allows you to use much powerful syntax and performs much better than XPath:

- http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax
- http://jodd.org/doc/csselly/

See this tutorial:

- http://www.testingdiaries.com/jmeter-cssjquery-extractor/

Comment: Thanks for your response , it worked with regular expression extractor

Comment: thanks but it is better with css/jquery. You should accept an answer

Answer (score 0):

You do not click on a link in JMeter. Instead just use the value of the `href attribute` of the link you want to click in the `Path` of the HTTP request.